# How to stop script execution on the loss of internet connection and resume again on re-connection of internet?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception

I have a test script which has 30K test data and it has to be tested using selenium automation.
Assuming that my 10K tests have already run and I lost internet connectivity, here I want to handle the internet connectivity exception.

Can this be done using selenium, or we need a 3 party tool to handle this? Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can write before lanunch test some pre-test for testing if internet connection is present and wait some time for rerun. You can add it for instance in  @BeforeClass annotation (for TestNG of JUnit). If internet connection is present, the main test can start.